# I am getting following error when I try to create a new angular project

Tags: node.js, angular

Could someone please help me with this error? I am trying to create a new angular app using `ng new app-name` but I get the following error, I am new to angular and not sure of the reason for this error.

```
CREATE angular-app/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (307 bytes)
CREATE angular-app/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:231:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:596:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:596:3)
```

Comment: Can u please check this thread , https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10206

Answer (score 2):

There are two solution for this issue

**solution 1**

*uninstall node global packages and update npm and reinstall global packages*

**solution 2**

*There is workaround when you create a new project*

```
 --skip-install --skip-git on ng new
```

from Angular Issue [Board](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10206#issuecomment-379246173)

Answer (score 0):

This may also be related to the version of Node used. I had a very similar error when trying to start an Electron application. I noticed my global version of Node was 13 but the version of Electron in the project I was trying to run was 12. When I switched to version 12 with nvm, re-ran npm install - the error disappeared.